# Reference variable in java is not changing its state

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
class Cat {
    String name;
    float time;

    void action(){
        if (time >= 0 && time < 8) {
            System.out.println("I am sleeping");
        } else if (time >= 8 && time < 12) {
            System.out.println("I am playing");
        } else if (time >= 12 && time < 19) {
            System.out.println("I am sleeping");
        } else if (time >= 19 && time <= 24) {
            System.out.println("I am playing");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat1 = new Cat();
        Cat cat2 = new Cat();

        cat1.name = "kali";
        cat2.name = "lali";

        Cat time1 = new Cat();
        Cat time2 = new Cat();
        Cat time3 = new Cat();
        Cat time4 = new Cat();

        time1.time = 3;
        cat1.action();

        time2.time = 9;
        cat1.action();

        time3.time = 15;
        cat2.action();

        time4.time = 21;
        cat2.action();
    }
}
```

I expect the following output:

```
I am sleeping
I am playing
I am sleeping
I am playing
```

However I am getting the following output:

```
I am sleeping
I am sleeping
I am sleeping
I am sleeping
```

Why is it so?

As far I can decipher the state of the variable `time` is here constant and is not changing as per new input.

Comment: the time variables you update are not related to your cat1 and cat2 variables

Comment: Maybe update `cat1.time` instead of `time1.time`? (etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because you are executing the action operation over a different instance (e.g. cat1 instead of time1). As those are instance variables, they are only scoped on that instance.

The below would solve your problem:

```
time1.time = 3;
time1.action(); // instead of cat1

time2.time = 9;
time2.action(); // instead of cat2

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the answer I was looking for, I knew that other answers would give me correct results.

Answer (score 3):

you have to do something like this :

```
Cat cat1 = new Cat();
Cat cat2 = new Cat();

cat1.name = "kali";
cat2.name = "lali";

cat1.time = 9;
cat1.action();

cat1.time = 15;
cat1.action();

cat2.time = 9;
cat2.action();

cat2.time = 15;
cat2.action();
```

Because you have 6 object different and  you are changing time object `time1, time2, time3,time4`. cat1 object is not connected with `time1, time2, time3,time4`

Answer (score 0):

Desired output is possible,

By calling action method of instance variable `time1, time2, time3, time4` respectively and not `cat1`

Or

By making `float time;` a static/class variable as `static float time;`. This way value of `time` will be shared by all instances of the `Cat`

Following is the updated code for second option.

```
class Cat {
    String name;
    static float time;

    void action() {
        if (time >= 0 && time < 8) {
            System.out.println("I am sleeping");
        } else if (time >= 8 && time < 12) {
            System.out.println("I am playing");
        } else if (time >= 12 && time < 19) {
            System.out.println("I am sleeping");
        } else if (time >= 19 && time <= 24) {
           System.out.println("I am playing");
        } else {
           System.out.println("Wrong input");
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Cat cat1 = new Cat();
    final Cat cat2 = new Cat();

    cat1.name = "kali";
    cat2.name = "lali";

    Cat.time = 3;
    cat1.action();

    Cat.time = 9;
    cat1.action();

    Cat.time = 15;
    cat2.action();

    Cat.time = 21;
    cat2.action();
   }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't understand the second method, please edit your answer and answer in details